# ZF2 convert empty posted fields to Null

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using fieldsets in order to fill forms in ZF2. If an empty field is postedm, the field is also empty in the db. How do I force a Null in the db for empty fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ZF2 I think you need to use [Zend\Filter\Null](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.filter.null.html) or [Zend\Filter\ToNull](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.filter.null.html) depending on which version of ZF2 you are using, Zend\Filter\Null became deprecated in ZF2.4.

In your fieldset, assuming you are using the Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface use:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return array(
        'your_field' => array(
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'ToNull'),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```